# ng-if condition in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS and try to do hide show in angularJs.

Below is my Code :

```
  <ul class="recent-rate-list">
      <li ng-repeat="ratedType in ratedTypes">
          <a href="#" style="line-height:30px">{{ratedType.type}}</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

AngularJS :

```
        $scope.ratedTypes = [
        {
            type: 'Select All',
            "value": '0',
            isSelected : true
        }, {
            type: 'Option 1',
            "value": '1',
            isSelected: false
        }, {
            type: 'Option 2',
            "value": '2',
            isSelected: false
        },{
            type: 'Option 3',
            "value": '3',
            isSelected: false
        },
    ];
```

Where I need when isSelected = true then

```
      <a href="#" style="line-height:30px"><span>{{ratedType.type}}</span></a>
```

and when isSelected = false then

```
      <a href="#" style="line-height:30px">{{ratedType.type}}</a>
```

I know angularJs has ng-if, but I unable to use it. How can I solve it using ng-if?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put ng-if condition inside the div tag.

```html
<div ng-if="isSelected === true"><a href="#" style="line-height:30px"><span>{{ratedType.type}}</span></a></div>

 <div ng-if="isSelected === false"><a href="#" style="line-height:30px">{{ratedType.type}}</a><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather add like this-

```
<div ng-if="isSelected"><a href="#" style="line-height:30px"><span>{{ratedType.type}}</span></a></div>

 <div ng-if="!isSelected"><a href="#" style="line-height:30px">{{ratedType.type}}</a><div>
```

and in your controller define-

```
$scope.isSelected = false;
```

Hope this helps :)